# Linux kernel booting stops at Uncompressing Linux… Ok, booting the kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I have problem with porting `kernel v2.6.29` to the board on which I am able to run `kernel v2.6.20`.
It stops after printing

```
Uncompressing kernel........done, booting the kernel
```

I have enabled `DEBUG` in `boot/compressed/head.S` and I am able to get a memory dump of the kernel in ram. Also, `arch_id` and `proc_id` are correct , but it still does not go anywhere else.

Also I've tried getting info from `__log_buf` like described [here](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/LinuxPostMortemAnalysis) via `JLink` but I could not reach the address that I've got with grep. Probably it is wrong, but I don't understand why? Can somebody tell where else can I look for a solution or even better what can I do to fix this?

Here is some additional info:
**SoC**: Marvel NHPXA270C5
**Bootloader**: Redboot v3.4.2

Comment: (1) Make sure you have a valid console defined in the kernel command line.  (2) Enable earlyprintk.  See https://blackfin.uclinux.org/doku.php?id=linux-kernel:debug:early_printk

Comment: Stop using so antique kernel for the first.

Comment: @sawdust thank you for your reply. Concerning boot parameters I am sure that they are valid, because I am was not changing them. And I have a few images with kernel version 2.6.14 and 2.6.30 which are also booting with same params. About earlyprintk, I have add `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK` and print statements in `init/main.c` but it did not work out. Maybe I did something wrong there I am not sure. For some reason, it is not in kernel hacking, so I was supposed to add it manually to my defconfig.

Comment: @jww thanks, I will put my question there also. And will keep that in mind next time

Comment: @0andriy true, but it would not be an option in my case. I should not change bootloader, and I am not sure if newer kernel versions would work with this one, especially if 2.6 is the last version that was using `mach_id`

Comment: *"About earlyprintk, .... Maybe I did something wrong there I am not sure."* -- The link I provided tells you what you did wrong.  There are *two* steps to enabling earlyprintk, and you only mention performing one.  Without earlyprintk or similar, adding any *"print statements in init/main.c'* is usually futile.  *"so I was supposed to add it manually to my defconfig"* -- That's usually wrong, but apparently it doesn't matter.  Seems like 2.6.29 only supports earlyprintk on a few arches, like x86, SuperH and Blackfin.

Comment: What's preventing you to update bootloader?

Comment: @sawdust thanks, we were able to get early print with some kernel patching. And adding early print in boot args

Comment: @0andriy because customers want only update OS on devices, by changing memory cards (microSD). And they have a lot of this devices in the field.
But I'd preferred to change it if it was only possible.

Comment: Sad to be you. At some point your bootloader can't serve new kernels (that's what happend to U-Boot in approx. 2016).

Comment: @AndrewH *"I should not change bootloader, and I am not sure if newer kernel versions would work with this one..."* -- If you're referring to Device Tree blobs, then there is a workaround for "old" bootloaders, i.e. the blob can be appended to the kernel